# How do I limit upgrading to kernel 5.15, while staying on 5.13 HWE kernel stack with 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kernel, ntfs, ntfs-3g

5.15 kernel does come with bunch of cool new features, but I am not getting the confidence to upgrade given the bunch of bugs here & on other distro forums. Slower development & bug-patching of new NTFS3 kernel driver, since I do need to interact with NTFS most of the time, I am afraid to upgrade, hence wish to wait.

The question is, how do I block it, while keeping 5.13 HWE kernel? I wish to receive updates on other packages, but don't know how to do that selection.

Comment: You are aware the 5.13 kernel is EOL in Ubuntu, and by continuing to use it you won't have security patches/fixes applied.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has the GA kernel stack (5.4) or HWE which is now 5.15 (with 5.8, 5.11 & 5.13 now EOL & *unsupported*); plus some OEM options if suitable for your hardware.  If you're off-line you'll be safe, but you are aware of the security implications of your question aren't you  (the 5.15 kernel is LTS which matters & why it was used)

Comment: @guiverc yes, I might be forced to downgrade to GA 5.4 kernel or stick with 5.13 without updates, it's bad-bad both ways since I need working NTFS, very badly. I might wait out 22.04 LTS to see performance for ~ 2 months too.